# Why does `testparm` ignore log level setting?

Tags: server, 22.04, samba, configuration, log

My typical procedure for configuring Samba is with a config file named */etc/samba/smb.conf.master*. After configuration, I implement the changes with `testparm -s /etc/samba/smb.conf.master > /etc/samba/smb.conf`. But what I've found is that any setting of `log level = [0..10]` in */etc/samba/smb.conf.master* is ignored and not output to */etc/samba/smb.conf*. This doesn't mean the log files are completely empty. Instead, they are very bare minimum with just errors and warnings, as if the setting is default: `log level = 1`.

I've even tried setting the log level with the `-d` debug level option using `testparm` as follows. But this has no affect. The log level setting is still not passed to */etc/samba/smb.conf*.

`testparm -s -d 3 /etc/samba/smb.conf.master > /etc/samba/smb.conf`

All this being said, my current solution is to directly edit */etc/samba/smb.conf* after-the-fact and add my log level setting with `log level = [0..10]`. Subsequently, the level of logging is set as intended and reflected in the log files correctly.

With some research, the answer to this Stack Exchange question, [Unable to modify log level in samba](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129384/unable-to-modify-log-level-in-samba), says that *you cannot use testparm to test this because it forces the log level to 2*.

Is this is intended behavior? If so, why? And is there a better workflow so that I don't have to edit both files?

**Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server**

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

**Samba Version:**

```
$ smbd -V
Version 4.15.13-Ubuntu
```

Comment: Try `log level = 10`. I think that setting includes 1-9, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @waltinator I’ve tried every log level, and none are passed through to `smb.conf` when using `testparm` as I’ve indicated